# How to use LIKE for mysql search with JOIN and ORDER BY the count of most rows/votes in the vote table?

Tags: php, mysql, search, join, count

I have three tables I need to use in a search, Movies, Reviews, and Votes. I want to use the LIKE function for Movie.Title and Review.Subject and order them by the amount of the most votes for each match.

In the Votes table there is a ReviewID, UserID, IsGood. Every time a user votes, an insert is done with the MovieID, UserID, and 1 or 0 for the IsGood, 1 meaning good 0 meaning bad.

So one review may have 0 good and bad votes, or 5 good and 3 bad, etc. I would like to show the results in the following order:

**Review 1 - 10Good / 3Bad**

**Review 2 - 4Good / 3Bad**

**Review 3 - 0Good / 0Bad**

The matches with the most good votes at top, the ones with the most bad votes at the bottom.

This is the mysql query I wrote up and is obviously wrong, but hoping someone can help me out:

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT m.Title, r.Subject, v.ReviewID FROM Movies m
        LEFT JOIN Reviews r
            ON m.ID=r.MovieID
        INNER JOIN Votes v
            ON r.ID=v.ReviewID
        WHERE (m.Title LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
            OR r.Subject LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
        ORDER BY MAX(COUNT(v.IsGood='1')) LIMIT 10")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: You'll need to do a group on `m.Title, r.Subject, v.TipID`, or do a sub select to calculate the number of votes received.

Comment: Thx Paul for your response. Can you show me an example? maybe a link? I'll search on what you just suggested.

Comment: try just adding `GROUP BY m.Title, r.Subject, v.TipID` just before the ORDER BY clause, that should do it!

Comment: I just tried it, I'm getting a "Invalid use of group function" error... also I corrected my typo above from "TipID" to "ReviewID"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a fuller answer. 
To get the sum or good votes and bad votes from a set of joined table rows, you need to group the like rows together.

Below *should* give you the desired result.

```
mysql_query("
    SELECT m.Title, r.Subject, v.TipID, sum(v.IsGood) as IsGood, sum(v.isBad) as isBad FROM Movies m
        LEFT JOIN Reviews r
            ON m.ID=r.MovieID
        LEFT JOIN Votes v
            ON r.ID=v.ReviewID
        WHERE (m.Title LIKE '%" . $search . "%'
            OR r.Subject LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
        GROUP BY  m.Title, r.Subject, v.TipID
        ORDER BY sum(v.IsGood) desc, sum(v.isBad) asc LIMIT 10")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: I did the sql query like you showed me here. But it returns 0, now my question is, if I currently have no votes, would that be the issue? Do I need to add some sort of if condition to check if there are votes first?

Comment: I just added some votes, and now it works perfect. Ok, from here I'm a lil indecisive on how I should approach the votes. Should I add something to check if there are votes first? One would think the matches with no votes deserve to be in the middle of the list due to not being good or bad, right?

Comment: You should probably just change the `INNER JOIN` on Votes into a `LEFT JOIN` which will results in Movies being returned even there are no votes