# How to check if rows exist during a mysql search JOIN query?

Tags: php, mysql, join, group-by, having

I have this sql search query that works, but it only works if votes exist in the votes table.

```
mysql_query("SELECT m.Title, r.Subject, SUM(v.IsGood) AS Good, SUM(v.IsBad) AS Bad
    FROM Movies m
        JOIN Reviews r
            ON m.ID=r.MovieID
        JOIN Votes v
        ON r.ID=v.ReviewID
    WHERE (m.Title LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR r.Subject LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
        GROUP BY m.Title, r.Subject
    ORDER BY SUM(v.IsGood) DESC, SUM(v.IsBad) ASC LIMIT 10")
```

So I've changed it to this below so that no matter if there is 0 votes it should still show. But it doesn't pull any results, can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
mysql_query("SELECT m.Title, r.Subject, COUNT(v.ReviewID) AS Rvotes, SUM(v.IsGood) AS Good, SUM(v.IsBad) AS Bad
    FROM Movies m
        JOIN Reviews r
            ON m.ID=r.MovieID
        JOIN Votes v
        ON r.ID=v.ReviewID
    WHERE (m.Title LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR r.Subject LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
        GROUP BY m.Title, r.Subject, v.ReviewID
            HAVING Rvotes >= 0
    ORDER BY SUM(v.IsGood) DESC, SUM(v.IsBad) ASC LIMIT 10")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want results even when no votes exist in the *votes* tables, [`LEFT JOIN`](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php) the *votes* table.

```
mysql_query("SELECT m.Title, r.Subject, SUM(v.IsGood) AS Good, SUM(v.IsBad) AS Bad
    FROM Movies m
        JOIN Reviews r
            ON m.ID=r.MovieID
        LEFT JOIN Votes v
        ON r.ID=v.ReviewID
    WHERE (m.Title LIKE '%" . $search . "%' OR r.Subject LIKE '%" . $search . "%')
        GROUP BY m.Title, r.Subject
    ORDER BY SUM(v.IsGood) DESC, SUM(v.IsBad) ASC LIMIT 10")
```

**Note:** I've modified your initial query (not the second) as you said it still didn't provide what you wanted.

Comment: This works, but now I'm only getting one result. I have one movie and two reviews, if i enter the name of the movie in the search and only one of the reviews show up, not both. I would like for all matches to show up. What would I need to change? Thanks btw.

Comment: I think your query is doing too much. You may want to backup and reform your question.

Comment: Well this is extension of my original question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914475/how-to-use-like-for-mysql-search-with-join-and-order-by-the-count-of-most-rows-v/8914664#8914664 Here you'll see my original request.

Comment: You should really not duplicate questions. I would recommend you delete this one.

Comment: I didn't see it as a duplicate, more like I'm trying to get from A to C and was stuck at B... Anyways, I tried deleting it but I can't at this point... Any ideas on why I'm getting only 1 result?

Comment: Not without knowing the sample data. Sorry. To stick with you're analogy, you've only shown me B. I'd likely need A, C, D to be more helpful.